# How can HISAT2/StringTie report decimal coverage values

Tags: rna-seq

I have performed RNA-seq analysis using HISAT2 & StringTie workflow suggested in: [Transcript-level expression analysis of RNA-seq experiments with HISAT, StringTie and Ballgown](http://www.nature.com/nprot/journal/v11/n9/full/nprot.2016.095.html).

Some of the transcripts/exons have decimal coverage values (eg., 1.1 or 2.59).

**My question is:** How can these tools report decimal coverage? If only half of the read overlaps exon will this exon have 0.5 coverage?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect this is average coverage across the transcript or exon.

Formula for average coverage:

[image: coverage-formula]

Where:

- N: number of reads mapping/aligning to your transcript/exon
- L: average read length
- T: Transcript/exon length